# Restart countodown timer with different timer android

Tags: android, timer, restart

I am making a repeating countdown timer app.I require the countdown timer to restart with a different time.I am using a global variable in the constructor of the countdown timer.But the problem is that it always restarts from the starting of the first given interval.

```
public void chance(final int tota, final int cur, final int exercise,int pass,int flag)
    {
    Log.i("inside value","reached");


         a = new CountDownTimer((tempmilliseconds) * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
             @Override
             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                 tempmilliseconds = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                 Log.i("inside value",Integer.toString(tempmilliseconds));
                 updatetimer(millisUntilFinished);
             }

             @Override
             public void onFinish() {
                 mtext.setText("0:00");
                 cancel();

                 final Handler handler = new Handler();
                 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         currentcompleted++;
                         if (on == 0) {
                             on = 1;
                             int exercis = MainActivity.restmint * 60 + MainActivity.restsec;
                             tempmilliseconds=exercis;
                             chance(tota, curr + 1, exercis, 0, 0);
                         } else {
                             on = 0;

                             int exercis = MainActivity.exermint * 60 + MainActivity.exersec;
                             tempmilliseconds=exercis;

                             chance(tota, curr + 1, exercis, 0, 0);
                         }
                     }
                 }, 1000);

             }
         };
         a.start();
     }
```

Below is the code for resume operations:

```
public void resume(View view) {
        Button mytext=(Button) findViewById(R.id.resume);
        if( mytext.getText().toString()=="Pause") {
            mytext.setText("Play");
             a.cancel();
        }
        else {
        mytext.setText("Pause");
        Log.i("Value of temp",Integer.toString(tempmilliseconds));
          a.start();
        }
}
```

The timer is stopping but when started in the resume function restarts with the original time and not specified by tempmilliseconds.Note tempmilliseconds is updated every seconds.
Any help/snippets/suggestions is appreciated.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A `CountDownTimer` will not allow itself to be disturbed in any case. It will remember the time it was born with till someone kills it.

If you look at its documentation you'd see that it directly inherits from `Object` class and has only four methods: `start()`, `cancel()`, `onFinish()` (abstract) and `onTick()` (abstract). Thats pretty much it. So, you basically are left with no choice but to call `cancel()` and then re-initialise the timer. Or, you can extend the `CountDownTimer` class and encapsulate this under the hood.

In either case the cost of cancelling ad re-initialising may get tedious.